# File verification and validation

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this code here made in a more simplified way:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {

    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    let N = /^(N1\d{14}.{78}|N2.{70}|N3.{82}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$/;

    for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
      if (N.test(lines[line])) {
        console.log(lines[line]);
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid register = ", lines[line]);
      }
    }
}
```

What I want is a way that a message can be shown to tell me that the file corresponded to all those requirements and if not that a message can be printed to tell me that the file is not valid, but keep showing me the message at the console. How can I possibly do that? Another question I have is if there is a way to specify that can be only one register called `N1`

**HERE IS A FILE EXAMPLE**

```
N108258594000135255240708     315370        BLABLA BLABLABL BLAB BLA                          
N2BLA2222016BLABLA BLABLABLA                                3525.250    
N3BLABLABLABL.EXE                                   01BF011351A2B06D7A88048CBDDC53CE
N908234944000135255240708     000016
```

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead for the first N1 `^(?:N1(?!.*N1)\d{14}.{78}|N2.{70}|N3.{82}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$` but not that for example `.{70}` could also possibly match multiple times `N1`

Comment: If it matches multiple times then a message should show me that the file is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there should be no occurrences of 2 times N1, you could use a negative lookahead `(?!.*N1.*N1)` at the start of the pattern asserting not 2 times `N1`

```
^(?!.*N1.*N1)(?:N1\d{14}.{78}|N2.{70}|N3.{82}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hx54vq/1)

To keep the messages and show a message after the loop if all have passed, you could for example introduce a variable and give it a default value of true.

If there is a line that does not match, you change the variable to false.

For example

```
// By lines
var lines = this.result.split('\n');
let N = /^(?!.*N1.*N1)(?:N1\d{14}.{78}|N2.{70}|N3.{82}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$/;
var passAll = true;

for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
    if (lines[line].trim() === "") continue;
    if (N.test(lines[line])) {
        console.log(lines[line]);
    } else {
        passAll = false;
        console.log("Invalid register = ", lines[line]);
    }
}
console.log(passAll === true ? "All lines passed" : "Not all lines passed");
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to make it consider the ```line break```? Because when it gets to the end of the line there is no other line and he is giving me the ```Invalid register``` thing

Comment: @Lagaggio I have added this line `if (lines[line].trim() === "") continue;` which will check for an empty line and will then issue `continue` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are processing each line one by one and it is an error if there is more than one "register called N1", i.e. a line that passed the regex test and begins with N1. So you have to keep track of whether you have already seen such a line:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
var invalidRegister = false;
var seenN1 = false;
reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {
    // By lines
    var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    let N = /^(N1\d{14}.{78}|N2.{70}|N3.{82}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$/;

    for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
      let s = lines[line];
      if (N.test(s)) {
        if (s.substr(0, 2) == 'N1') {
          if (seenN1) {
             console.log("Repeat N1 register = ", s);
             invalidRegister = true;
             continue;
          }
          seenN1 = true;
        }
        console.log(s);
      } else {
        console.log("Invalid register = ", s);
        invalidRegister = true;
      }
    }
    if (invalidRegister) {
      console.log('The file is not valid.');
    }
};
```